# I use the rvm1.8.7,but when i use to install the rails v=2.3.11 it throws the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (= 2.3.11) in any repository

any one help me Pleace

Comment: Try to run `gem env` and paste the output here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gem install rails -v=2.3.11` or `gem install rails --version=2.3.11`

Comment: I have try the gem install rails --version=2.3.11. it throws the same error:ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (= 2.3.11) in any repository

Comment: is there is another way to install the rails version=2.3.11 when i use the rvm 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

This [method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203632/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repository/204022#204022) should solve your issue:

```
$ gem install --http-proxy http://201.187.107.19:8080 rails
```

Note, the IP address and the port number refers to a proxy. You should search for a proxy list and use one of the proxies there.

This is sample site with proxies: http://www.cybersyndrome.net/pla5.html